# Record set not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, grouping, store, extjs-grid

I use a grouping feature on my grid. When I click on a group I simply iterate through my store and change some properties using set. But the attribute doesn't get set no matter what..
Here is my code:

```
onGroupClick(node, view, group){

    var store = Ext.getStore('someStore');

    store.data.each(function(item, index, totalItems ) {
        if (item.data.id == somecondition ){
            item.set('displayName', 'someName'); //DOES NOT WORK        
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**: the field being set uses a converter.

Comment: I don't know if this would cause the issue.  Does making the `each` method `store.each(function(item){});` effect? I'm seeing that it is possible to use each at the [store level in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each).

Comment: Is there any alternative option?

Comment: An alternative is `Ext.Array.each(store.data.items,function(item){});`

Comment: Sorry, I did not help!

Comment: Could try setting it directly, `item.data.displayName = 'someName'`? Additionally, are you positive that the condition is being met in the `if` statment?

Comment: The condition is not the problem. The way you described now is wrong for many reasons I believe and it does not work either...

Comment: right, you should use `set()` however, i was curious if setting directly got diff outcome.  Is there any error reported in console?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the field converter code. Could you post that?